# How to prevent caching in Cache.db-wal file in iOS App which contain Salesforce iOS SDK

Tags: security-review, ios, caching

My iOS App rejected by Salesforce security review team with following reason.

"Insecure Storage of Sensitive Data" and show this file path  /private/var/mobile/Applications/96998CD5-5C0F-490C-8E2C-FD8835F2014E/Library/Caches/com.companyname.appname/Cache.db-wal

So how to prevent chaching to resolve this issue.

Please help me I would like to submit my app to Salesforce security review team again ASAP.

Answer (score 5):

I presume this is a native app built using the Force.com Mobile SDK for iOS. This is a standard iOS procedure to disable caching on your `NSURLRequest`

Some sample code as provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405151/is-it-possible-to-prevent-an-nsurlrequest-from-caching-data-or-remove-cached-dat)

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url
      cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData
      timeoutInterval:60.0];
```

Then create the connection

```
NSURLConnection *conn = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request
       delegate:self];
```

and implement the connection:willCacheResponse: method on the delegate. Just **returning nil** should do it.

```
- (NSCachedURLResponse *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse *)cachedResponse {
  return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Gaurav's answer didn't quite do it for me, so I figured I'd add my 2 cents.

I observed that the caches were persistently being saved in the app's `Library/Caches/<company app identifier>/Cache.db-wal`. Even after setting the cache policy of the request, it continued to store data here. I was able to resolve the issue by wiping out this file after each request.

```
+(void)destroyNetworkCache {

    NSString *caches = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, TRUE) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *appID = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary][@"CFBundleIdentifier"];
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/Cache.db-wal", caches, appID];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:path error:nil];
}
```